# Xamarin get/insert data from MySql hosted on another PC

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.android

I want to building an android app by Xamarin, C# language. This app can get or insert data to MySQL, this SQL hosted on another PC
So, Where I can get information and tutorial for this?
Thank you!

Comment: *"Where I can get information and tutorial for this"* - Unfortunately, this question is not suitable for stack overflow. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Basically if your MySQL database is in another computer, you need to communicate to it over web, I would suggest you use API, in computer with database make API Application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0
There is microsoft documentation for it.

Create endpoints for specific actions, and then communicate with them from your Xamarin App, here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

- Create API service on computer with database
- Communicate from your application to API (then API communicates with database, and sends back results to your Xamarin App)

I personally like RESTful principles for API's. documentation: https://restfulapi.net/

You should also consider adding authentication to API, so that only apps you want, can GET/INSERT data to your database

Answer (score -1):

to get data from mysql in any app you need to API:
i using ASP webservice to get data from mysql
then in Xamarin.Android APP in refrence folder click right and add web refrence .
watch this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTZ8pbWAVW4&list=PLF8OvnCBlEY3qYheTm4gnaoWwBuBf2TUj&index=46

Comment: what is web service ?https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF8OvnCBlEY1sUaRzfo1u07hM4kRDjhfj

Comment: you can using API or REST API or WCF rather than web service

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.